# Name an Object with a Variable - Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, object

I am trying to create objects within a script but I'm failing to understand how to create an object by using a variable to name it, See below:

```
objname = "object"  # < Var used for Obj name

class SimpleClass
    def initialize(name)
    end
end

objname = SimpleClass.new("Jeff")  #does not work
# ^ using a variable to name the object

workingname = SimpleClass.new("Jeff") # will work
```

P.S
Y'all are the best, From a beginning programmers prospective I don't know where I would be without this site.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... what do you mean when you say `objname = SimpleClass.new("Jeff")` doesn't work?  Doesn't the variable `objname` contain a SimpleClass instance?

Are you saying you want a variable called `object` to contain the object?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do ... You're assigning the string `"object"` to the variable `objname`, without using the variable afterwards. Then, you're assigning (thus replacing) your `SimpleClass` instance to `objname`.

Comment: No no, I would like to use a variable to call an object the contents of the variable, So in the non working one I would like the object to be called object. Not objname. But I can't write that into the code because the code I am applying it to needs to create objects. Thus it would have to name then differently as well. So a variable would have to be in place for the name so that I can write a name to that variable earlier in the script then use it to name an object.. I hope this helped :) I am extremely new to classes and how they interact.. This must be very hard to understand

Comment: @Stefan let me guess: it’s a try to achieve smth like `eval("#{objname} = SimpleClass.new('Jeff')")` :)

Comment: @Gittb Despite what you are trying to achieve, your design is bad. You are never supposed to need the floating variable names.

Comment: @mudasobwa EXACTLY! but I do receive an error if I attempt to run that.. test.rb:13: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
eval(#{objname} = SimpleClass.new('Jeff'))

Comment: @Gittb The double quotes in my snippet were _mandatory_.

Comment: @mudasobwa the variable `object` will fall out of scope immediately and will not be accessible outside of the eval method. The OP will get "undefined local variable or method 'object' for main:Object" if he tries to do it this way.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, that was just a demo. But `objname='@myobj' ; eval("#{objname} = 5") ; p @myobj` would work perfectly.

Comment: @mudasobwa yes because instance_variables will not suffer from the same scoping constraints but using an example that has no possibility of doing what was requested seems misleading especially to someone who is clearly very new to ruby. Chances are this will make the OP feel like they have done something wrong when in reality you provided a concept that never had any chance of working.

Comment: @engineersmnky You might notice, that my comment contained “smth like” wording, was not addressed to OP and was not published as an answer. You might as well notice, that the concept in fact works, the value is _perfectly assigned_.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you would want to do this but it could be preformed using instance variables like this

```
objname = "object"  # < Var used for Obj name

class SimpleClass
  def initialize(name)
  end
end

instance_variable_set("@#{objname}", SimpleClass.new("Jeff")) 
#=> #<SimpleClass:0x228a548> 
@object
#=> #<SimpleClass:0x228a548>
instance_variable_get("@#{objname}")
#=> #<SimpleClass:0x228a548>
```

All that being said this is a poor design concept and as you can see it would be easier to just use a standard local variable as your code will be littered with instance_variable_get/set methods which perform no actual purpose in this context.